# gradle kotlin script configuration for javascript

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-js

For jvm i can use:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.60"
}
```

I have found no equivanent string for "jvm" for use with javascript and am using the following:

```
plugins {
    id("kotlin2js") version "1.2.60"
}
```

So the questions. 
Is there an equivalent string to "jvm" to for javascript or some other more direct equivalent to the 'kotlin("jvm")'?

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: It doesn't work since plugin for JS isn't published yet on Gradle Plugins Portal. 
Feel free to vote for the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20156

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is taken as "not yet"  - and no current plan for that to change either.   So stick with the id().

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work since plugin for JS isn't published yet on Gradle Plugins Portal. Feel free to vote for [the issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20156).

As a workaround, you can add to your settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "kotlin2js") {
                useModule("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your build.gradle.kts files you can write like

```
plugins {
    id("kotlin2js") version "1.3.10"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-js"))
}
```